# WordPress Search Problems

Tags: wordpress, search, http-status-code-404

I have researched this problem and still can't seem to figure out why my search function isn't working on a theme I'm working on.  Below is my code that I have for my search.php and my searchform.php files.  The search files were hardly modified from a boilerplate, blank WordPress theme.  When I search for anything, it returns a 404 error.  I have researched search's returning 404's and still can't find the solution.  Blow is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

searchform.php----------------------------------

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>" id="searchform" method="get">
        <label for="search"><object data='<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?    >/images/input-search.svg'>
        <img src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/input-search.png'>
        </object></label>
        <input type="search" name="search" />
</form>
```

search.php---------------------------------------

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <h2>Search Results</h2>

    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

            <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>

            <div class="entry">

                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

            </div>

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <h2>No posts found.</h2>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your search form is enabled in your functions.php file like so:

```
 // ENABLES SEARCH FORM STUFF
 function my_search_form( $form ) {

$form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
<div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __('Search for:') . '</label>
<input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__('Search') .'" />
</div>
</form>';

return $form;
```

}

```
 // ENABLES SEARCH FORM
 add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'my_search_form' );
```

This is the code I use in my themes. Then this would call in my search form:

```
 <?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

This is my searchform.php

```
    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
     <label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search' ); ?></label>
     <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search' ); ?>" />
     <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search' ); ?>" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Well I figured out why it was returning a 404 -
I actually had my <?php get_search_form(); ?> wrapped in an additional form tag so there was a form tag in my HTML as well as my searchform.php file.

However, the search results query a ../?search=xxx now but it returns every post in the database.  Any guesses as to why?

Comment: Try removing action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>" out of your searchform.php and putting action="$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']" instead... Let me know if that works

Comment: That didn't seem to do it.  That went back to returning a 404.

Comment: Hmmmm... Your searchform.php is different to mine, here's mine:

I'll edit my answer...